# Проблема с написанием мини-калькулятора

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая в зависимости от значений в объекте(или передаваемых через функцию call()) выполняет различные операции. Пока это просто калькулятор, который принимает первое число, второе число и действие, затем вычисляет и выводит результат. 
Вот код:

```js
function calc(num1, num2, act) {
 let res;

 if (typeof this.num1 !== 'number' || typeof this.num2 !== 'number') {
  res = 'Введите числа в правильном формате';
 }

 switch (this.act) {
  case '+':
   res = this.num1 + this.num2;
   break;
  case '-':
   res = this.num1 - this.num2;
   break;
  case '*':
   res = this.num1 * this.num2;
   break;
  case ':':
   res = this.num1 / this.num2;
   break;
  default:
   res = 'Введите действие в правильном формате';
   break;
 }

 console.log(res);

 return this;
}

let obj = {
 num1: 2,
 num2: 3,
 act: '+',
 calc
};

calc.call(6, 5, '-');
```

Вместо результата выводится default, вроде все нормально.

Comment: `let obj = {
 num1: 2,
 num2: 3,
 act: '+',
 calc: calc
};

obj.calc(6, 5, '-');`

Comment: Вы уже прочитали описание метода `call`?

Comment: `this` внутри функции - пустой

Comment: Похоже, я просто невнимательно читал описания `call`.